# How to install salt for python3?

Tags: python, saltstack

When I check my `salt-minion` version, I get the following message:

```
[root@localhost ~]# salt-minion --version
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/scripts.py:198: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as
Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date.  Salt will drop support for Python 2.7 in the Sodium release or later.
salt-minion 2019.2.0 (Fluorine)
```

My question is: how can I install Salt for python3, since the salt packages are automatically installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/salt/`?

OS is `CentOS 7`.
Installed salt through `Yum`, from this repo: https://repo.saltstack.com/#rhel

Comment: Well, the directions are right on that page you linked!

Comment: Oh, now I see... there's a different repo for python3. I think I didn't see it when I copied this repo a couple years ago. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in https://github.com/saltstack/salt-bootstrap#python-3-support
this is only supported on some platforms.

Try

```
sh bootstrap-salt.sh -x python3 -D
```

and/or check `sh bootstrap-salt.sh --help` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You just use the python3 package installer - pip3

```
yum install python3-pip
pip3 install salt
```